# How to make provable an unprovable sequence of true assertions?

Tags: logic

Suppose an assertion $A$ says that $A_n$ is true for any $n=1, 2, \dots$, and each $A_n$ can be verified by a finite procedure. Also assume that there is no finite proof of $A$ for all $n$ at once. This means that $A$ is "true" but unprovable, the axioms chosen are not strong enough for proving $A$. On the other hand, how do we know then that **all** $A_n$ are true? As far as I understand this, we know somehow that $A$ is undecidable, and then if some $A_n$ were false, we could discover this with a finite chain of arguments. Is this correct? Are there universal rules for such situations? Say, what would be quite satisfactory: can one add any axiom of universal type which would allow us to make such assertions provable?

Comment: Do you have an example of this situation in mind? Maybe your $A$ is something like [Goodstein's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem)?

Comment: Are we working in a specific model or are you saying that for each $n \in \Bbb N$, there's a finite proof of $A_n$ from your axioms?  It makes a big difference.

Comment: @Karl: yes. I also meant [Hilbert's tenth problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem), and at least some [in the list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_undecidable_problems) are like this.

Comment: @Robert: I meant the latter, while I don't understand your former case.

Comment: Hmm, how does Hilbert's tenth problem fit the description? What are the $A_n$ and $A$?

Comment: For the example of the Diophantine equation, one should check if a countable family of collections of integers contains a solution.

Comment: I see, so for some sufficiently hard diophantine equation with no solutions, $A_n$ is "tuple $n$ is not a solution" and $A$ is "there is no solution".

Comment: Yes, thanks for the explicit formulations.

Comment: Anyway, for these these kinds of questions one has to be careful to keep track of the theory/model/system associated with statements of provability. When we say that a statement is true but has no proof, it's because we *can* prove it in some metatheory (like ZFC) but can also prove (again in the metatheory) that it's not provable in some weaker system of interest (like PA).

Comment: I see my question could be specified in the sense of choosing concrete models like PA and ZFC so that statements that are unprovable in the former become provable in the latter. But from related MSE questions (which appeared on the page after I published my question) it follows that in general this does not work.

Comment: $\mathsf {PA}$ and $\mathsf {ZFC}$ aren't models.  They're theories.  The standard model of arithmetic (i.e., the model with no non-standard integers) is an example of a model.